# Merging compressed files on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, compression, apache-pig, hdfs

How do I merge all files in a directory on HDFS, that I know are all compressed, into a single compressed file, *without* copying the data through the local machine? For example, but not necessarily, using Pig?

As an example, I have a folder /data/input that contains the files part-m-00000.gz and part-m-00001.gz. Now I want to merge them into a single file /data/output/foo.gz

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest to look at FileCrush (https://github.com/edwardcapriolo/filecrush), a tool to merge files on HDFS using MapReduce. It does exactly what you described and provides several options to deal with compressions and control the number of output files.

```
  Crush --max-file-blocks XXX /data/input /data/output
```

`max-file-blocks` represents the maximum number of dfs blocks per output file. For example, according to the documentation:

> With the default value 8, 80 small files, each being 1/10th of a dfs
>   block will be grouped into to a single output file since 8 * 1/10 = 8
>   dfs blocks. If there are 81 small files, each being 1/10th of a dfs
>   block, two output files will be created. One output file contain the
>   combined contents of 41 files and the second will contain the combined
>   contents of the other 40. A directory of many small files will be
>   converted into fewer number of larger files where each output file is
>   roughly the same size.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the Parallel to 1 - then you will have single output file.
This can be done in 2 ways:

1. in your pig add `set default_parallel 20;` but note that this effect everything in your pig
2. Change the Parallel for a single operation - like `DISTINCT ID PARALLEL 1;`

Can read more about [Parallel Features](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/cookbook.html#Use+the+Parallel+Features)

Answer (score 0):

I know there's an option to do merging to the local filesystem using "hdfs dfs -getMerge" command. Perhaps you can use that to merge to the local filesystem and then use 'hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal" command to copy it back into hdfs.

Comment: But I want to avoid having to transfer the data back and forward to the local filesystem.